# what is the alternative of AlarmManager to schedule long duration time tasks in Oreo?

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager, android-workmanager, foreground-service

I am creating an app that will set the android device in silent mode automatically every day at 8:00 am?
I used AlarmManager , Job-Scheduler with foreground service but it will not work on android 8 or above .. I also use WorkManager but WorkManager requires certain constraints to run the job.. plZzz Help me

Comment: Can you describe more about limitation of `WorkManager` with your problem? `WorkManager` is next-gen of Alarm or JobScheduler. How far did you tried with it?

Comment: When you are using service in android Oreo or later, please consider the [behaviors that have changed](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes)

Comment: AlarmManager perform task on exact timmings, How can i use WorkManager to replace AlarmManager? WorkManager does not guarantee that the work will done on time.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend sticking with a `Worker`, it is a simpler parallel to `WorkManager` but without mandatory constraints. `Worker` and `WorkManager` automatically handle lower SDK versions by stepping-down to AlarmManager.

I've replaced my app's `AlarmManager` with `Worker`, it is much more stable for periodic tasks.

All you need is a Worker class `MyPeriodicWorker.class`:

```
public class MyPeriodicWork extends Worker {

    private static final String TAB = MyPeriodicWork.class.getSimpleName();

    public MyPeriodicWork(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull WorkerParameters workerParams) {
        super(context, workerParams);
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Result doWork() {
        Log.e(TAB,"PeriodicWork in BackGround");
        // Run your task here

        return Result.success();
        }
    }
```

and a `WorkRequest` instance called from another class. In your case, you want a `PeriodicWorkRequest` for a recurring task. You must specify the parameter for flex if you want the task to run at the specified time (minimum flex of <5 minutes early):

```
    PeriodicWorkRequest mPeriodicWorkRequest = new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(MyPeriodicWorker.class,
            periodMS, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, periodFlex, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .addTag("PeriodicWorkRequest")
            .build();
```

The above is all you need to use it, then use `WorkManager` `enqueue` to start.

```
    WorkManager.getInstance(context).enqueue(mPeriodicWorkRequest);
```